# Any suggestions how to fix and get WeightPlot and WeightEditor tabs?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I can't find the solution on how to fix Errors in the code. Any advice would be helpful.

```
package weightmonitor;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class WeightMonitor extends JFrame {

    //menu
    JMenuBar mainMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New Weight File");
    JMenuItem openMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open Weight  File");
    JMenuItem saveMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Save Weight  File");
    JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");

    //

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //create frame
        new WeightMonitor().setVisible(true);
    }

    public WeightMonitor() {
        //frame constructor
        setTitle("Weight Monitor");
        setResizable(true);

        setJMenuBar(mainMenuBar);
        mainMenuBar.add(fileMenu);
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);
        fileMenu.add(openMenuItem);
        fileMenu.add(saveMenuItem);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);



        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                newMenuItemActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });

        openMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                openMenuItemActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });

        saveMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                saveMenuItemActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });

        exitMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                exitMenuItemActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
                exitForm(evt);
            }
        });

        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gridConstraints;

        pack();
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds((int)(0.5 * (screenSize.width - getWidth())),
            (int)(0.5 * (screenSize.height - getHeight())),
            getWidth(), getHeight());
    }



    private void newMenuItemActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
    private void openMenuItemActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
    private void saveMenuItemActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
    private void exitMenuItemActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}



    private void exitForm(WindowEvent evt) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class WeightPlotPanel extends JPanel {
    //Declaration of tab control and panels
    JTabbedPane weightTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel editorPanel = new JPanel();
    WeightPlotPanel plotPanel = new WeightPlotPanel();


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Rectangle2D.Double plotFrame;
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g2D);

        //draw plot frame
        plotFrame = new Rectangle2D.Double(50, 40, 420, 280);
        g2D.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
        g2D.fill(plotFrame);
        g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g2D.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2D.draw(plotFrame);

        g2D.dispose();
        //pack();

        weightTabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        weightTabbedPane.addTab("Weight Editor", editorPanel);
        weightTabbedPane.addTab("Weight Plot", plotPanel);
        GridBagConstraints gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 0;
        getContentPane().add(weightTabbedPane, gridConstraints);

        editorPanel.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 255));
        editorPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        plotPanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 192, 192));
    }
}
```

IntelijIdea says

> Error on "getContentPane().add(weightTabbedPane, gridConstraints);"

but I don't know how to fix it. The IntelijIdea gives the option to create a `private` method but is there any other way to fix this. Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

No need to get `getContentPane()` When you extend JFrame or JPanel! You are already in a container. Just call add to add a component to the container.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class WeightMonitor extends JFrame {

    //menu
    JMenuBar mainMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New Weight File");
    JMenuItem openMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open Weight  File");
    JMenuItem saveMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Save Weight  File");
    JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");

    //

    public static void main(String args[]){
        //create frame
        new WeightMonitor().setVisible(true);
    }

    public WeightMonitor(){
        //frame constructor
        setTitle("Weight Monitor");
        setResizable(true);

        setJMenuBar(mainMenuBar);
        mainMenuBar.add(fileMenu);
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);
        fileMenu.add(openMenuItem);
        fileMenu.add(saveMenuItem);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);



        newMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
                newMenuItemActionPerformed(e);  }
        });

        openMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
                openMenuItemActionPerformed(e);  }  });

        saveMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
                saveMenuItemActionPerformed(e);  }  });

        exitMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
                exitMenuItemActionPerformed(e);  }  });

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
                exitForm(evt);
            }
        });

        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gridConstraints;

        pack();
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds((int) (0.5 * (screenSize.width - getWidth())),
                (int) (0.5 * (screenSize.height - getHeight())),
                getWidth(), getHeight());
    }



    private void newMenuItemActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {  }
    private void openMenuItemActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {  }
    private void saveMenuItemActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {  }
    private void exitMenuItemActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {  }



    private void exitForm(WindowEvent evt){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class WeightPlotPanel extends JPanel
{
    //Declaration of tab control and panels
    JTabbedPane weightTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel editorPanel = new JPanel();
    WeightPlotPanel plotPanel = new WeightPlotPanel();


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Rectangle2D.Double plotFrame;
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g2D);

        //draw plot frame
        plotFrame = new Rectangle2D.Double(50, 40, 420, 280);
        g2D.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
        g2D.fill(plotFrame);
        g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g2D.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2D.draw(plotFrame);

        g2D.dispose();
        //pack();

        weightTabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,  400));
        weightTabbedPane.addTab("Weight Editor", editorPanel);
        weightTabbedPane.addTab("Weight Plot", plotPanel);
        GridBagConstraints gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 0;
        add(weightTabbedPane, gridConstraints);

        editorPanel.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 255));
        editorPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        plotPanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 192, 192));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JPanel inherit the class java.awt.Container, so the class JPanel is a container itself.

There is no implementation of the method getContentPane().

Replace the line

```java
getContentPane().add(weightTabbedPane, gridConstraints);
```

by

```java
add(weightTabbedPane, gridConstraints);
```